# Some questions on setting default application on given file extension on MAC OS X from code

Tags: objective-c

I set DVDPlayer.app as the default application for file extension .mkv with the function LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType.

Right click on abc.mkv, in the open with menu, the DVDPlayer has been the default application.
Methods as bellow also return DVDPlayer.app:

LSCopyDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType

LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType

LSGetApplicationForInfo

But check abc.mkv's file info in Finder, its default is still QuickTime Player.

And double click on abc.mkv just launches QuickTime Player.

Why? Is there anything else to do for double click ?

What makes me so confused is that the info got by LSGetApplicationForInfo is different with shown in Finder's info! Confused...